# Removing multiple input names on output formdata strings/arrays with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, output

I figured it out using the /=on/g global value and it worked there... Thanks for the help ^_^ 
Any other advice is appreciated though! :D

---

I currently am having difficulty trying to figure out where to put the `formdata.Replace` to remove all `=on` tags after output from my form.

I have multiple check boxes, the ones that are submitted go to the next page and it displays all the inputted data. However, it also keeps the `=on` tag from the javascript and I can only figure how to remove one of them. I'm assuming I need to input another loop somewhere, but I am confused as to how to do that since there is an unknown number of checkboxes they can choose at one time (this output is being used on multiple pages, and there's different numbers of checkboxes per page).

This is the original script I found:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- HIDE FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS
if (window != top)
 top.location.href=location.href
document.write("<h1>Your form has been submitted!</h1><h2>You entered the following data:</h2>");

var formData = location.search;
formData = formData.substring(1, formData.length);

while (formData.indexOf("+") != -1) {
 formData = formData.replace("+", " ");
}

formData = unescape(formData);
var formArray = formData.split("&");

for (var i=0; i < formArray.length; ++i) {
 document.writeln(formArray[i] + "<br />");
}

// STOP HIDING FROM INCOMPATIBLE BROWSERS -->
</script>
```

I added  `formData = formData.replace("=on", " ");` in the while loop, which removes the first one but not any of the other ones.  I am not sure where to put it, however.

Comment: where is the `replacereplace("=on", " ")` function in the given code??

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to be careful with that code, unless you don't expect user-generated input, as you may end up replacing something that you didn't want to. There are a few JS libraries that will pull out the submitted values for you in a much safer way that you may want to research.

The issue that you're encountering is that it will only replace `"=on"` as many times as it replaces `"+"` with `" "`. If you add an additional while-loop, you can replace `"=on"` until they're all gone.

```
while (formData.indexOf("+") != -1) {
 formData = formData.replace("+", " ");
}

while (formData.indexOf("=on") != -1) {
 formData = formData.replace("=on", "");
}
```

Comment: We have a bunch of photos that they can select and it gets emailed to us, but we just have it output for them to verify their selection since they won't see it again when they go to buy the product it's going on :) Past that,the data doesn't need to be saved. Just emailed to us when it's submitted :)